# Using "the" for institutions

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions, definite-articles, writing

I would like to know when we use "the" for the institutions particularly when it is written in letters or newspapers as title/body.

As far as I understood, you don't put "the" for the title while use "the" for the body in a letter.

For example:

> Title:  21st National Assembly   or  Embassy of the United States in Brazil
> Body: The 21st National Assembly has a plenary session.....  / The Embassy of the United States expresses its compliments....

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: There's no general rule.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A definite article before government institutions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/260529/a-definite-article-before-government-institutions)